# How to find the difference between epoch time stamp in java

Tags: java

How to find that current  epoch time stamp is lies between the given two  epoch time stamp in java.

Comment: How would you do it if you had to find out if `b` is between `a` and `c`?

Comment: Define "epoch"...Java only has one, when the `Date` value is `0`, 01 Jan 1970...

Comment: Just compare the values like numbers!

Comment: If your epoch is in long format, I guess you could just subtract? If not, just convert it and do that.

Comment: As the others commented, you are misusing the word "epoch". Read this Wikipedia article on [Epoch (reference date)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29)

Answer (score 0):

as @Akstar suggested, you can just use the `Java Date`. 
The `Date.getTime()` method returns a `long` representing the number of milliseconds since epoch.

Therefore, just convert the `Date` objects to longs and compare the values.

Answer (score 0):

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library is a popular replacement for the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date & Calendar classes bundled with Java.

In Joda-Time, a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object represents a point on the timeline of the Universe. While similar to java.util.Date, a DateTime is different in that it does know its own time zone.

Joda-Time offers an [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class that defines a beginning and ending on the timeline. The Interval is "**half-open**" meaning the beginning is *inclusive* and the ending is *exclusive*. Half-open is usually a good way of handling a span of time. An Interval object offers a `contains` method to test if a given DateTime lies inside or out.

```
Interval interval = new Interval( new DateTime( 2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ), new DateTime( 2013, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ) );
DateTime now = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );
boolean isNowInThatInterval = interval.contains( now );
```

You would find many such questions already answered if you search StackOverflow before posting.

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe what you are talking on is a time stamp (instead of "epoch time stamp") right?

Given time stamp in Java is usually represented by a `java.util.Date`, there are some ways you can use:

(assuming we are implementing a method `static boolean isBetween(Date myDate, Date date1, Date date2)`, and assuming you don't know which of `date1` and `date2` is earlier)

1. using the Long representation of the date e.g.  `return myDate.getTime() < time1.getTime()) != (myDate.getTime() < time2.getTime()));`
2. using Date's `after/before` method. e.g. `return (myDate.after(date1) != myDate.after(date2));`
3. Joda have nice APIs to represent range of date time, like `Interval` which you can make use of `contains()` to determine if it contains a specific time.